# Using C++ to read a file on a remote Linux-type server

Tags: c++11, server, samba, smb

I am building a small network of Raspberry Pi's using Raspian with samba file sharing.  I want each to be able to read/write small text files to the others, to provide a very simple method of process co-ordination.  I am a testing the method with one Pi with a single shared file and can read/write to it from an Ubuntu laptop, using its desktop file manager.  I am trying to do the same programmatically:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void read_file () {
    string line;
    
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("\\\\192.168.1.78\\home\\pi\\new2.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        cout << "file is open" << endl;
            getline(myfile, line);
            cout<< line << endl;
    } else {
        perror("Error");
    }   
    myfile.close();
}

int main(){
    read_file();
}
```

The error message is 'No such file or directory'.  I'm guessing this is either a permissions problem I've not seen (the remote file is shared as 777) or the way I'm referencing the server and folder.  I've tried numerous combinations to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you're planning to connect using ssh, you'll need to interact with an ssh library. C++ doesn't support networking by default in its `fstream` library, and if your implementation (by some bizarre chance) does happen to support it, it'll be incredibly non-portable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'd seen a number of references to  'fstream' using network path names, although they are all using Windows and I can't be sure if any of them actually work, I guess It's either ssh or sockets or something out-of-the-box like mosquitto.

Answer (score 1):

Using backslash paths like this wouldn't work on an Ubuntu system. The fact that this works in your file manager is probably due to the file manager being smart and handling mounting and path conversion transparently for you.

What you need to do is to mount the shared folder yourself so you can use a regular Linux file path to open it. See this question on how to mount SMB shares with Samba: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99065/how-to-mount-a-windows-samba-windows-share-under-linux

Comment: Thanks for the link - I followed the example closely but the remote directory still fails to mount.  I'm also getting occasional crash reports and core dumps from Ubuntu.  Rather than dig into possible causes, I'll drop the Ubuntu and try it with a Raspbian Pi - closer to what I'm  actually building, and dump the backslashes, which I gather are a hangover from ancient Windows systems.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. If it fails on the RPi too, I suggest opening a separate question on superuser/unix about the errors you get.